# Vim-Matlab Errno 2 No such file or directory

Tags: neovim, error, matlab

I just installed the plugin provided by daeyun here:
https://github.com/daeyun/vim-matlab

But when I open up an M-file in Neovim, go to connect to the server with the command `:MatlabLaunchServer` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USER/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-matlab/ftplugin/matlab/../
../scripts/vim-matlab-server.py", line 193, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/USER/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-matlab/ftplugin/matlab/../
../scripts/vim-matlab-server.py", line 183, in main
    server.matlab = Matlab()
  File "/home/USER/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-matlab/ftplugin/matlab/../
../scripts/vim-matlab-server.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.launch_process()
  File "/home/USER/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-matlab/ftplugin/matlab/../
../scripts/vim-matlab-server.py", line 39, in launch_process
    close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

[Process exited 1]
```

I get the same exact error when running the `vim-matlab-server.py` in my `scripts` folder using the following command

```
/home/USER/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-matlab/scripts/vim-matlab-server.py
```

I couldn't find this issue anywhere online.
Also, I have reinstalled the plugin multiples times and it gives the same error everytime.

Any ideas or suggestions for how I should troubleshoot?

Comment: Looking [at the code that fails](https://github.com/daeyun/vim-matlab/blob/master/scripts/vim-matlab-server.py#L38-L39), it seems it can't find the `matlab` executable. Make sure that it's installed somewhere in your `PATH`.

Comment: Has this been resolved? I agree with Martin's comment but see no indicator that it solved BLI's question.

Comment: @MartinTournoij My Matlab is installed in my user directory `/home/blinux/MATLAB/bin/matlab`
Not sure if that counts as `PATH`, is there a way to configure the plugin so that it will be able to find my executable? Thanks for your help in this.

Comment: @Martin I was able to add the `matlab` executable to my path and now can run MATLAB by typing `matlab` onto my command line. However, I am still getting the same when using the `:MatlabLaunchServer` command in Neovim.